# Any ideas to display SLD TextSymbolizer property in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, sld

I'm trying to display the SLD TextSymbolizer property for a vector layer in OpenLayers but I found that it's not supported.

Has anyone ever dealt with this issue?

I found these links but I have not ideas about how to implement them

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/1542

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/2816

Answer (score 1):

Check Out http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/sld.html and http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-features-with-text.html it might help.

Comment: None of them answer my question: "Display SLD TextSymbolizer property in Open Layers". Thanks anyway.